# Delay/smooth sensors & buttons (not software side)

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, integrated-circuit, delay

**Is it possible to create long rising/falling delays/heavy smoothings only using capacitors and basic electronic elements ?** (alternatively also IC's, but no 555)

This is what i know:

1. Capacitior's help to smooth/delay sensors, buttons, potentiometers everything.
2. To delay a button for 1s a 1000uF/(10k?? resistor) capacitor is needed.
3. To smooth a potentiometer i add capacitors on both signal->gnd vcc->gnd
4. Adding many big capacitors like the 1000uf is not good. (adding the resistor after the cap will blow your circuit because of the high current rush)
5. The delay of a button is only in "one direction" it takes very long time to charge but discharginging is very fast. hence its high/low exactly the moment you pressed but it takes time to be ready again.

Are there some electronic tricks to create delays on "both directions" at an equivalent delay time. I know it's stupid for a button but its simple way to explain it.

```
Press a button -> 1sec delay -> send high pulse -> 1sec dealy -> rdy
```

Basically increase the time it takes to go from high2low & low2high

```
|0v----|1v----|low----|3v----|high----|5v----|
|30sec---------------------->|---------------| 
|-------------|<------------------------30sec|
```

Sensors:

I have a very responsive sensor . i want it to take alot more time to change it's value on the ADC. **30 seconds. Do i need really big caps to do that?**

Example:

ir distance sensor, it takes let's say 50nanoseconds or whatever (to fast for me to notice anyway) to move from 1v to 4v and the same from 4v to 1v.

What i want is that it takes 30sec to move from 4v to 1v but also 30sec from 1v to 4v. 
Even if it swings between 3v & 4v it should stay in the middle... 3.5v it it starts at 4v and then swings fast from 2v to 4v it should slowly reach 3v.

**If it works, is there a simple calculation (and maybe circuit diagramm) to get the average time it takes to do those delays ?**

It would be fantastic if there is also a way to control the delay time with a precision potentiometer... but again, NO 555.

**EDIT**

example of a button ...if i press really fast it does nothing. i need to hold the button for at least 10sec to activate it. then it should be ready again after 10sec when i remove the finger.

Putting this type of button circuit on an adc would allow to use the ADC value as NONLINEAR countdown.....

**EDIT2**

After some thinking...another solution would be a DAC with a super low controllable response time???
Do they exist?

**Is this the following possible?**

[image]

the ripple and pulse is the signal.

the "gray supersmooth" larger line should be the output.

like i said the the output delay should be controlable.

**EDIT3**

**LOW PASS FILTER** should do the trick?

what to say... until now i never heard of low pass filters... sorry.
i'm just starting. i'm a programmer. got a raspberry as gift ... read about gpio's got some arduino's and now i'm here asking stupid questions about electronics.

**EDIT4**

This?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5mryR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A low pass filter with something like 1000uF cap & 2kΩ resistor should be 0.080Hz which is 12.5 seconds?

Does this mean it takes 12sec to move from 0v to 5v & from 5v to 0v?

**EDIT5**

***A low pass filter with 1000uF & 6k ohm would delay the response from 0 to 4.99v in 30 seconds. this not considering the sensor resistance and the ADC resistance*** Solving all my above questions.

thank you all for contributing.... i learned alot of new things today!

*but... you guys , and by that i mean Electronic Engineers ... you should tell those noobs that they need low pass filters in most sensors!!! even buttons.. try to google arduino circuits with adc stuff or even simple buttons.... no caps no low pass filters... awww*

Comment: Can you write one or two lines of what you have and what you want? preferably with some waveforms / time graphs.

Comment: lol no .. i'm not an electronical engineer. i just want to learn new stuff. general(maybe some more advanced) delays in electronics. An idea could be to use th distance sensor to open a door but it should take 30sec to open but only if you are at 20cm & it should let enter the next person only after 30s

Comment: but there are many other situations where some sort of delay is necessary ... doing it the hw way could be a solution.

Comment: anyway you know better than me the response of various sensors or other input devices. some are slow some are to fast. I just want to control them over time without using software. the button is the simplest example. it oscillates from high to low various times on a normal press with a low resistor and no capacitor

Comment: btw if you talk about the circuit i will use mcu's to read the ADC. it can be 3.3v or 5v. i can write the code for that but i think it can be done with electronics components. An excuse to learn more.

Comment: I would try to use a OpAmp.

Comment: so opamps do delays? the only thing i know about opamps is that they increase heavely the input voltage but they are used for everything else than that.

Comment: No. But they allow you to do your delay with much smaller CAP, as they have an extremely high input resistance

Comment: isn't a just a resistor enough to increase the charging time of a capacitor? btw i have only a cheap multimeter. no oscilloscope.

Comment: notice ... it should work in both directions. not only charging.

Comment: If I understand you right, you need a extreme LowPass?
Yes, by increasing your output resistance, the cap can be smaller to get the same time. What is at the output of your circuit?

Comment: temp sensores have different amounts of time it takes to stabilize at the correct value, also voltages vary . distance sensors , tilt sensors i mean everything. i feed those sensors let's say with an 5v arduino ... some sensors consume uA's. but i also use sometimes 3.3 devices. So everything is between 0v and 5v and shlould consume less than 100mA to exagerate. an analog to digital input pin is used to read the voltage. some have 8bit ranges some 12 some 16. no software delay.

Comment: I'm just tring to understand how far a circuit can go vs software (knowing that with software this is relatively easy). If it's even possible do something like that.

Comment: Another example of a button ...if i press really fast it does nothing. i need to hold the button for at least 10sec to activate it. then it should be ready again after 10sec when i remove the finger

Comment: From my little expirience this could be possible with a 555 & a big cap. maybe to get it working correctly it would need 2 555 but the components should be not so complex ic's

Comment: Write down what you want to happen and forget about guessing at solutions. If I press this then nothing happens for 10 seconds etc.. If this input goes high then nothing happens for ten seconds etc etc.. Don't pre-guess a solution because at the moment your question is weak on requirements and big on solutions that cannot be totally justified.

Comment: take that example . when i press the button the voltage should slowly increase ... 1v/8sec... when i remove the finger the button should slowly drop 1v/5sec.  i know my mcu takes the high value a 2.8v and the low value at 1.4v for example.is that possible? btw i need nothing in particular... i'm trying to understand if complex bidirectional delays are possible using simple electronic components

Comment: "weak on requirements and big on solutions" start with the simplest example that comes into your mind... if you want a supersimple precise example: enable the switch only after 10sec.(as soon as the button is pressed increase slowly the voltage that goes to the IO of an mcu). from 0v to 2.8v in 10sec... it can continue to 5v... or drop if removing the finger...

Comment: but then again thats not what i'm asking...  i'm trying to understand if complex bidirectional delays are possible using simple electronic components... And an example circuit would be a good answer. where the input is always an ADC or a simple high/low IO of an mcu

Comment: i mean the output... while the input is a variable voltage from 0v to 5v

Comment: it should take those a specified time to reach its new value. if it's oscillating it should slowly reach the center of the ripple/oscillation. Is that possible?

Comment: i think there are not many "big on solutions" using simple components.

Comment: it should act like and dac but with a very low controllable response.

Comment: it would be nice if you explain the downvotes so i know what i did wrong.

Comment: You are not looking for a delay, but for a filter. And it will not be bidirectional. Bidirectional would mean, that the sender and receiver switch position. You just want to have rising and falling edge treated the same way. This is the case for a low pass.

Comment: with "bidirectional" i was thinking only about capacitors. high is fast ... low takes the charging time. now yeah... a "low filter" should be the answer then... never made a low pass filter... now i know they are called low pass filter. you mind showing me an example as answer? thank you.

Comment: A low pass filter with something like 1000uF & 2kΩ should be 0.080Hz which is 12.5 seconds? Does this mean it takes 12sec to move from 0v to 5v & from 5v to 0v?

Comment: it's really hard here for someone who knows nothing about electronics to get a concrete answer.

Comment: This site is sadly rather hostile to newbies, especially to people who don't yet know enough to phrase questions "properly". But I'm not sure where's a better place to point people at; maybe the eevblog forums? The arduino/raspberry pi stackexchange sites?

Comment: lol i'm watching all his videos lately... ;) and yep... i didn't know about low pass filter. Somehow i was sure something like that exists. Some engineers here should have pointed out that much earlier... but it's ok. now i know. True the programmers side of the stack networks share alot more knowledge. Here they know more but keep it very tight!!!!.

Comment: i'm also in the arduino stack, raspberry stack and mostly stackoverflow... i love javascript and general web stuff programming

Comment: but i must admit it... i love the vagueness of the answers in EE. it's understandable... EE is complicated stufff and telling wrong stuff can have bad consequences....So the use of analogies and never give a concrete answer is a must... until every detail about what you are about to do isn't clear. At the other side you need to keep also the question short and omit some obvious context.So basically it's impossible to get a "normal" answer. it's ok. with some downvotes ,some patience, & lots of comments you get a proper response. wrong code can be corrected a burning circuit not. thx EEguys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit 4 is already a good start. 
Have a look at the following pages: [RC Circuits](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html) and [RC LowPass](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_2.html). They will show you the basics.

To your schematic: 
In order to be somehow precise with the times you calculate you need to know the resistance of the ADC and the sensor as well. Or you could add a [OpAmp as voltage follower](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/analyze-noninverting-op-amp-circuits.html) at the entry and output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDv2iK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 1.i calculated 0.08Hz which is 12.5 sec... does that mean it takes 12.5seconds to go from 0v to 5v and something like 6seconds to go back to 2.5v? 2. i didn't know adc have resistance... i prolly need to look into the mcu's datasheet? 3. what exactly does the opamp in this low pass filter circuit?

Comment: 3: For a simple Lowpass we don't need a opamp.
1: How did you calculate this 12.5s?
Normaly you calculate tau = R * C what makes with 1mF (HUGE!) and 2k (small) = 2s. Tau means that it your cap charges from 0V to ~0.6*Vmax. 
2: Yes. The datasheet will specify the input resistance

Comment: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Low-pass-filter-calculator.php#answer1 https://www.unitjuggler.com/convert-frequency-from-Hz-to-s(p).html?val=0.0795774715

Comment: No it does not. It means that the highest Frequency to pass with less than 3db loss (half size) is 0.8Hz

Comment: vmax is 5v the time it should take from 0-5 is 30seconds.  R is in kohm and C in mF?

Comment: then tau*(.6*5v)/.6*1 = timeItTakesFrom0-5v?

Comment: 10 seconds from 0 to 5v with 1000uF & 2k ohm?

Comment: so 1000uF & 6k ohm would be the 30seconds?

Comment: is that correct?

Comment: btw at this high timespans the sensor resistance but also the adc internal resistance should have almost no impact ... right?

Comment: the system is never fully charged. But after 5 tau you have reached 99.9% of your 5V (and yes: 5*2s = 10 sec)

yes 30 seconds can be reached with a 6k R

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31868/discussion-between-botnic-and-cocco).